# Create-React-App DNS module error with jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dns, json-web-token

I am having an error where I can not decode the authorized token on the client side app. I've found fixes for my problem but they are only able to be fixed in custom webpack.configs. I am using create-react-app build and have been stuck on this for some time now. here's an example of what my error is.

```
   ./~/isemail/lib/isemail.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'
```

This error occurs when I try to use the npm module "jsonwebtoken" on the client side to decode my authorized token. If anybody has a fix to this or can explain a way to initialize the dns node as empty I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need to decode the JWT on the client side?

Comment: I'm trying to decode the user information to display whom is logged in when the token is recieved